# How to know if an a2dp device is connected from udev rule

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I am trying to determine if an a2dp sink is connected to my system each time a connection happens on bluetooth. I am using these rules:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", RUN+="/bin/sh -c '/home/myuser/on-connect-bluetooth.sh'"
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", RUN+="/bin/sh -c '/home/myuser/on-connect-bluetooth.sh'"
```

I thought about using `pactl` but according to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1579554/udev-rules-to-run-pactl/1579574#1579574) it is accessible only by a user, which udev is not. DBUS was mentionned but it is not clear to me how it could be leverage through a simple shell and without delving deep into the kernel API...

Through the udev rule I know the devpath in `/sys/devices/` but there seems to be little information in there.

How can I know if an a2dp sink is present upon bluetooth connect/disconnect event?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, albeit imperfect because relying on a third party tool which then needs to be installed and maintained, is:

```
bluetoothctl info | grep 0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

`0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` is a2dp UID.